# Resizing a video in Premiere without scaling

Tags: premiere, aspect

I have a video that's 1280x720.

I want it to be 720x720 without re-scaling it (e.g., I simply want to cut off the excess on the right). I need to embed it on a website which is why the sizing sounds strange.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Create a sequence that is 720x720, drag the clip on to the timeline, and in the canvas window use the arrow tool <kbd>v</kbd> to double click the layer which brings up the layer controls. Position it the way you want, export.  I'm pretty sure Premiere doesn't scale non-uniformly by default.

If it does for some reason, you'll probably want to use the conform options to adjust how it is conformed to the sequence.

You'll need to use a custom sequence setting since none of the presets will match your 720 by 720.  You'll also want to make sure you use square pixels (1.0 pixel pitch) if you are looking for a perfectly square output.

Comment: You can also use the position settings in the effects window for the clip. You'd want to set the x coordinate to 640.

Comment: @Stib, thanks for the edit.  It's been a bit since I used Premiere now that I've switched over to Resolve as my go to and didn't have my Premiere machine handy.